# Javascript inheritance problem

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I don't seem to be able to overwrite class methods correctly, using the following code ...

```
function core() {
    console.log( "CORE CONSTRUCTOR CALLED" );
}

core.prototype.output = function() {
    return 'CORE';
}

function sub1() {
    console.log( "SUB 1 CONSTRUCTOR CALLED" );
    this.core();
}

sub1.prototype = core.prototype;
sub1.prototype.constructor = sub1;
sub1.prototype.core = core;

sub1.prototype.output = function() {
    return 'SUB 1';
}

function sub2() {
    console.log( "SUB 2 CONSTRUCTOR CALLED" );
    this.core();
}

sub2.prototype = core.prototype;
sub2.prototype.constructor = sub2;
sub2.prototype.core = core;

sub2.prototype.output = function() {
    return 'SUB 2';
}

var oCore = new core();
var oSub1 = new sub1();
var oSub2 = new sub2();

console.log( oCore.output() );
console.log( oSub1.output() );
console.log( oSub2.output() );
```

... I get the following output ...

```
CORE CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
SUB 1 CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
CORE CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
SUB 2 CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
CORE CONSTRUCTOR CALLED
SUB 2
SUB 2
SUB 2
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is... when you are issuing the line:

```
sub2.prototype = core.prototype;
```

You are using the SAME prototype on `sub2` as `core`, thus when you call `.output()` from *ANY* of the classes, the function at `core.prototype.output` is the `sub2` version as it is the last one defined.  Remember, object assignments happen by reference.

To copy the object you would commonly see:

```
sub2.prototype = new core();
sub2.prototype.core = core;
```

Or - if you want to avoid calling the constructor, you could use jQuery's `$.extend(sub1.prototype, core.prototype);` to copy the core prototype.  If you don't have jQuery, this is about the same:

```
sub2.prototype = {};
for (var method in core.prototype) sub2.prototype[method] = core.prototype[method];
sub2.prototype.constructor = core;
sub2.prototype.core = core;
```

Comment: Not using JQuery for this (purposefully trying to avoid tying the code to a JS framework) but the bottom example worked perfectly. Thankyou.